# Meaning of Pattern at derivatives of arbitrary functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, argument-patterns

I want to derivate some general functions like

```
D[F[x[r_, p_], y[r_, p_]], r]
```

or this simpler one

```
D[F[G[x_]], x] .
```

When I execude these commands I do not get a general derivative for arbitrary functions, but some code wit `Pattern^(1,0)` or `F1(1,0)`. What do these Patterns mean? Can't figure it out by myself.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full form of `G[x_]` is `G[Pattern[x, Blank[]]]`, so taking the derivative with respect to `x` applies the chain rule, treating `Pattern` as any other symbol. In particular, the result will contain `Derivative[1, 0][Pattern][x, Blank[]]`.

See also the documentation for [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html), [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html), [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html) and [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html).